# python list: put all repeated items into one tuple

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples

I simplified my question into this:
I have a list of items and I want to put all consecutive repeated items into one tuple.

```
li = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 1]
# now i want this:
result = [1, (2,2), 3, (4, 4, 4), 3, (5, 5), 1]
```

Please help me!

Comment: [have you tried anything?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Aside: that's not a very sensible thing to want.  A list of tuples, even if some of them only have length 1, is much easier to work with than a mixed list of integers and tuples.

Comment: I'v tried this: [(x, li[li.index(x)+1]) if x==li[li.index(x)+1] else x for x in li]. but it wasn't what i want.  
Consider that the actual list is a list of objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group together the consecutive equal values in the list. This allows you to first get a list of tuples containing the consecutive values; this may (or may not) be easier to work with in the long run.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> li = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 1]
>>> tups = [tuple(t) for _, t in itertools.groupby(li)]
```

`tups` is a list of tuples which looks like this:

```
[(1,), (2, 2), (3,), (4, 4, 4), (3,), (5, 5), (1,)]
```

To replace all length-1 tuples with their single element, you could run another list comprehension over `tups`:

```
>>> [x[0] if len(x) == 1 else x for x in tups]
[1, (2, 2), 3, (4, 4, 4), 3, (5, 5), 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another way without using any external libs.
Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
a=[1,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,6,7]
print a
result=[]
buff=()
for i in a:
    if a.count(i)==1:
        result.append(i)
    else:
        for j in xrange(a.count(i)):
            buff += (i,)
        if not buff in result:
            result.append(buff)
        buff=()
print result
```

Now let's dive into it

```
 for i in a:
        if a.count(i)==1:
            result.append(i)
```

if element meets only once, just put it into result list

```
    else:
        for j in xrange(a.count(i)):
            buff += (i,)
        if not buff in result:
            result.append(buff)
        buff=()
```

If element meets in list more than once,  count how many times, than create a tuple and than, if there is no such tuple in the result list, add it to result list and output result.

```
    [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7]
    [1, 2, (3, 3), (4, 4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6, 6, 6), 7]
```